# SQL Export to Excel results to doc lock, cannot edit the sheet

Tags: sql, excel

please help me solve the following issues.

1. When I export a report from SQL reports 2005 the image logos are distorted a bit, and the sheets are locked so further editing and sorting is not possible.
2. When I unlock the the frozen cells, to allow sorting and editing, the whole sheets are scrambled due to merged cells used by headings and logos etc., how can I fix this?  I mean, how can I edit a sheet without messing up the whole look of the report sheet?

If the above problems cannot be solved or let say its a sort of limitation, please do advise or at least explain to me why.

Thanks and hope to hear a positive solution soon.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the SQL Report export to EXCEL is a bit of a mess, and the problem you mention is fairly common.

The only practical work around I've found, which is a lot of work, is to embend the image in a table, sizing your column width to match one of the ones in your report.

This seems to work in most of our cases, but depends a lot on your specific report.

Also, after unlocking your report, try to freeze the header rows before sorting/editing.